# Create three equally spaced (sub-) Layouts where 1st is on top and 3rd is on bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, space

I have tried quite a while and not found a convincing solution for the below Layout Problem. E.g. if I use a RelativeLayout as Container, I can use  for (sub-) Layout A

```
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

And for (sub-)Layout C

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

but then it seems impossible to place Layout B in such a way that the two spaces are of the same height. Does anyone see a solution for this in .xml?

[image]

Comment: give a & b layout id's and use (android:layout_below="@+id/the_id") for b & c. see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When stacking elements on top of one another, [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) is an easy choice. With sub-layout A and sub-layout C taking up only the space they need, the remaining space is then allocated to Sub-layout B and any spacing needed to fill the remaining space. This can be done by wrapping Sub-layout B in a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_layout_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub_layout_b"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_layout_c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You'll note the `FrameLayout` for `sub_layout_a` and `sub_layout_b` can be any layout - just make sure the `layout_height="wrap_content"` (or a fixed value) so that they only take the space they need.

The remaining space is allocated to the middle `FrameLayout` by using a `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"` - the `layout_weight` is what stretches it to fill all the remaining space. That allows us to then center the inner `sub_layout_b` within that space by using `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`, leaving an equal amount of empty space on either side of `sub_layout_b`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this (sorry I cannot test it right now):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Any_layout_type_you_want
        android:id="@+id/sub_layout_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </Any_layout_type_you_want>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <Any_layout_type_you_want
        android:id="@+id/sub_layout_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </Any_layout_type_you_want>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <Any_layout_type_you_want
        android:id="@+id/sub_layout_c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </Any_layout_type_you_want>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Fer, actually this is the same principle as the one from ianhanniballake, just using two equally weighted placeholders instead of a single one, vertically-centered. That solution should also do the job.